# 埋め込んだYouTube動画を左右中央に配置したい

Tags: css

```
<div id="wrapper" class="inner clearfix top">
<article class="clearfix">
<div id="content">
<div id="top_btn">
<ul class="clearfix">
<li id="about"><a href="about/index.html"><span class="l1">***
に</span>ついて</a></li>
<li id="area"><a href="area/index.html"><span class="l1">***</span>***
</a></li>
<li id="voice" class="mr0"><a href="voice/index.html"><span class="l1">***
</span>の声</a></li>
<li id="try"><a href="try/index.html"><span class="l1">無料</span>**</a></li>
<li id="price"><a href="price/index.html">料金</a></li>
<li id="faq" class="mr0"><a href="faq/index.html"><span class="l1">よく
ある</span>質問</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p class="btnContact text-center pc_none"><a href="contact/index.php">**<br>
<span class="bold">***</span></a></p>
<div id="Video">
<iframe width="485"
height="300"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h77UYU84VOI" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

このコードで現在次のように表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

動画を入れる部分をid=Videoなdivで囲み、

```
#Video {
  position:replative;
  top: **px;
  left: **px;
  bottom:**px;
  right:**px;
}
```

とスタイルシートで指定しているのですが、このrelative, は、写真の一番上右横の「良く有る質問」のアイコン写真、CSSでは

```
#top_btn ul li#faq a {
  background-image:url(../img/icon_faq.png);
  /* 略 */
}
```

で指定して確かにサーバに存在するモノにrelativeなのでしょうか？またabsoluteで簡単な実験をした事は有るのですが、ここまで作りこまれたHPでどうしたらいいのかわかりません。

この動画をもう少しセンター方向へ移動するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

宜しくお願い致します(m_m)。

Comment: 質問のタイトルには質問内容を簡潔にまとめた記述をしてください。

Comment: 大変すいません(m_m)...

Comment: ヘルプの「[良い質問をするには?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)」や「[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコードの書き方](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)」も参考になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

画面の横幅はブラウザによって変わるので、
中央に表示したいのであれば、`position:`を使うのではなくて`margin`を使用してはどうでしょうか。
スタイルで、

```
#Video iframe {
    display : block;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

のようにすることでセンタリングできると思います。

例：

```css
#Video iframe {
 display : block;
 margin : 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Video">
<iframe width="485"
height="300"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h77UYU84VOI" frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```